# 0 appears by default in textbox binded to double

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, textbox

In my WPF application I have a textbox binded to a double property like this

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Orientation, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

and the property is like

```
    private double _orientation;
    public double Orientation
    {
        get { return _orientation; }
        set
        {
            _orientation = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Orientation);
        }
    }
```

When I load the dialog, textbox appears with default value as 0.0, which I dont want. I want the textbox to appear empty.

Also, when I select All text in textbox and hit delete/backspace (clear all text in textbox), the Set property does not get fired to set nothing in the property. In short, I want to allow empty values in the _orientation variable. How can I do these two tasks.
Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you try with "double?" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to be able to have an empty value for your property, but a double doesn't support this: zero is *not* an empty value, it is zero.  If you want to be able to have an empty value too, you probably want your property to be nullable - so you should declare it instead as a `double?`.

This would probably fix your second problem too: the property isn't being set to your empty value, because the empty value can't be converted to a `double`.

Comment: It does not work when I remove text from the textbox. Event does not get fired. Infect when the textbox becomes empty, textbox border becomes red to show validation error.

Comment: @Daniel So, I also had to add TargetNullValue='' in the XAML to make it work. Thanks for the help though :)